# Eclipse debugger steps outside of for loop

Tags: c++

I have the following for loop:

```
  // There is a typedef prior: uint32_t        bmd2_uint32;

  1.  bmd2_uint32 momentIndex(0);
  2.  for (int t = 0; t < numMoms; ++t) {
  3.    bmd2_float64 momentR;
  4.    bmd2_float32 * dataR = new bmd2_float32[numSegs * numVars];
  5.    bmd2getnthframe(handle, momentIndex, &momentR, dataR, error);
  6.    checkError(error);
  7.    for (int i = 0; i < numSegs * numVars; ++i) {
  8.      std::cout << dataR[i] << std::endl;
  9.    }
  10.   delete[] dataR;
  11.   ++momentIndex;
  12.  }
```

When I step through a debugger, it proceeds through lines 1-12.  Then I do another step and it steps back to line 1 and continues through the loop again.  Is this a debugger error?  The problem is that momentIndex is 0 the second time through the loop.

Comment: In the second loop, what is the value of the index `t`? Is it `1` or something else? Also, what does `operator++` has to do with this? Is this the implementation of `a operator++`?

Comment: t is 1 so the loop goes twice.  I am wondering if possibly my ++operator() overload doesn't work AND the Eclipse debugger for some reason graphically highlights the line proceeding the for() line.  It is very hard to understand what the Eclipse debugger is doing if it seems to do inconsistent things like this.  I am sorry that this is not a compelling question but it's baffling nonetheless.

Comment: Need more info. What type is momentIndex? What function does the above code sit in? Please post more code and take us through the relevant call flows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such weirdness can happen in a couple scenarios:

1: Your object files are in an inconsistent state; perhaps an object did not get built that should have been. Clean, and rebuild

2: Optimizations are turned on in the compiler, and the compiler has rearranged some code for performance. Resolution is to disable optimizations.

In this case, a `clean and rebuild` solved the issue.